# getting a value from 2d list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to extract a value from a 2d list using nested list comprehension however I was not able to do so. it outputs a list of 2 values instead. it is possible to achieve that?

```
unique_scores = [37.2, 37.21, 39, 41]
students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
result = [score for student in students for score in student if student[1] == unique_scores[1]]
print(result)
```

"expected: Harry"
"the output is ['Harry', 37.21]"

Comment: You don't need a nested list-comp. Use   `[i[1] for i in students if i[1] == unique_scores[1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested comprehension for this.

```
result = [student[1] for student in students if student[1] == unique_scores[1]]
```